# plist won't load into array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, plist

I'm new to Objective-C, so there probably is a pretty easy solution for what I'm doing. The problem that I'm having is that for some reason, the following code doesn't add the contents from my plist file into my array:

In my viewDidLoad function:

```
// Grab information from the plist
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString *plistPath = [bundle 
    pathForResource:@"conversions" 
    ofType:@"plist"
];
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc]
    initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath
];
```

File "conversions.plist", in the same folder as the above code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Categories</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>Speed</string>
            <key>conversions</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>type</key>
                    <string>mph</string>
                    <key>description</key>
                    <string>mile/hour</string>
                    <key>multiplier</key>
                    <integer>1</integer>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>type</key>
                    <string>ft/s</string>
                    <key>description</key>
                    <string>foot/second</string>
                    <key>multiplier</key>
                    <real>1.466667</real>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>type</key>
                    <string>km/h</string>
                    <key>description</key>
                    <string>kilometer/hour</string>
                    <key>multiplier</key>
                    <real>1.609344</real>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>type</key>
                    <string>m/s</string>
                    <key>description</key>
                    <string>meter/second</string>
                    <key>multiplier</key>
                    <real>0.44704</real>
                </dict>
            </array>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>Distance</string>
            <key>conversions</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>type</key>
                    <string>ft</string>
                    <key>description</key>
                    <string>feet</string>
                    <key>multiplier</key>
                    <integer>1</integer>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>type</key>
                    <string>yd</string>
                    <key>description</key>
                    <string>yard</string>
                    <key>multiplier</key>
                    <real>0.3333333</real>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>type</key>
                    <string>mi</string>
                    <key>description</key>
                    <string>mile</string>
                    <key>multiplier</key>
                    <real>0.0001894</real>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>type</key>
                    <string>in</string>
                    <key>description</key>
                    <string>inch</string>
                    <key>multiplier</key>
                    <integer>12</integer>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>type</key>
                    <string>m</string>
                    <key>description</key>
                    <string>meter</string>
                    <key>multiplier</key>
                    <real>0.3048</real>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>type</key>
                    <string>km</string>
                    <key>description</key>
                    <string>kilometer</string>
                    <key>multiplier</key>
                    <real>0.0003048</real>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>type</key>
                    <string>cm</string>
                    <key>description</key>
                    <string>centimeter</string>
                    <key>multiplier</key>
                    <real>30.48</real>
                </dict>
            </array>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>Volume</string>
            <key>conversions</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>type</key>
                    <string>ft^3</string>
                    <key>description</key>
                    <string>cubic feet</string>
                    <key>multiplier</key>
                    <integer>1</integer>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>type</key>
                    <string>liter</string>
                    <key>description</key>
                    <string>liter</string>
                    <key>multiplier</key>
                    <real>28.31685</real>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>type</key>
                    <string>acre ft</string>
                    <key>description</key>
                    <string>acre foot</string>
                    <key>multiplier</key>
                    <real>2.3e-05</real>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>type</key>
                    <string>barrel</string>
                    <key>description</key>
                    <string>barrel [US, liquid]</string>
                    <key>multiplier</key>
                    <real>0.2374768</real>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>type</key>
                    <string>gallon</string>
                    <key>description</key>
                    <string>gallon [US, liquid]</string>
                    <key>multiplier</key>
                    <real>29.92208</real>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>type</key>
                    <string>quart</string>
                    <key>description</key>
                    <string>quart [US, liquid]</string>
                    <key>multiplier</key>
                    <real>29.92208</real>
                </dict>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: You cannot fetch the entire plist file into an array at a time.
I think you will have to fetch it using the key and then storing it into NSMutableDictionary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems to me that the root object in your plist is a dict and not an array, aren't you supposed to load it into NSDictionary?

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
```